# Ansible output format to send by mail

Tags: ansible, format, output

I am having problems when formatting the output of a command using ansible, in the output "output.stdout_lines" I have the following result:

```
    "stdout_lines": [
        "---",
        "server_data:",
        "- nodename: rsdcaservertest02Node01",
        "servername: server1",
        "hostname: rsdcaservertest02",
        "- nodename: rsdcaservertest02Node01",
        "servername: server2",
        "hostname: rsdcaservertest02"
    ]
```

This part is correct but when I want to send it by mail it does not arrive in the correct format:

Server List
"[u '---', u'server_data: ', u' - nodename: rsdcaservertest02Node01 ', u' servername: server1 ', u' hostname: rsdcaservertest02 ', u' - nodename: rsdcaservertest02Node01 ', u' servername: server2 ', u' hostname: rsdcaservertest02 '] "

Could you help me with the format so that it arrives with the line breaks and without the "'u"

thank you all and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following:

```
    body: |
      Lista de servidores
      '{% for line in lists.stdout_lines %}
       {{ line }}
       {% endfor %}'
```